# How to disable/enable JCE using javascript?

Tags: javascript, joomla, opacity, joomla1.5, joomla-content-editor

I am using Joomla! 1.5.26 and JCE 2.2.0.

I need to change the status of the JCE (disable/enable) using javascript. If disabled, then the editor is in readonly mode and the background is set to opacity 1.

When a user clicks on the edit/save button, the JCE should be enabled/disabled.

I found this links: http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/read_only_mode.php

I also found how I can disable the content (cross-browsers):

```
tinymce.get('editorID').getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', 'false');
```

However, this code doesn't work:

```
J('#editorID').css({opacity:1});
tinymce.get('editorID').getDoc().designMode = 'Off';
```

How can I change the JCE background opacity from javascript?

Will it be possible to set the readonly mode by javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To apply this setting correctly you have to insert the real tinymce id you can get a console using `tinymce.activeEditor.id`.

So you may use

```
var editor_id = tinymce.activeEditor.id;
tinymce.get(editor_id).getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', 'false');
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! I checked (using chrome latest version)

This code works:
var editor_id = tinymce.activeEditor.id;
tinymce.get(editor_id).getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', 'false');

Mine too:
tinymce.get('editorID').getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', 'false');

Doesn't work anyway:
tinymce.get(editor_id).getDoc().designMode = 'Off';
J('#editorID').css({opacity:1}); 

I would like to add the opacity background, how?

Comment: that would be another question (i suggest you open one)

Comment: I had 2 questions :-) The first one is ok, but not the second one: How can I change the JCE/(TinyMCE) opacity background from javascript?

Comment: this should do it: $('iframe#'+tinymce.activeEditor.id+'_ifr').attr('allowtransparency',true); . other attributes may be set to the iframe analog

Comment: In the end...this is working: $('#editorID_parent').fadeTo(0, 0.5);
jQuery fadeTo is a cross-browser function. You helped me to find the solution, thanks!